set background gradient over multiple html sections
I have multiple sections each with the background.
It is not possible to wrap all sections in a div or container due to the nature on the build.


.grad-back{
background: rgb(0,92,109);
background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0,92,109,1) 0%, rgba(1,12,14,1) 39%, rgba(1,9,10,1) 65%, rgba(0,93,110,1) 100%);
}
section {
height:200px;
}
<section class="grad-back">one</section>
<section class="grad-back">two</section>
<section class="grad-back">three</section>



What we would like is the same background over all sections so the gradiant starts on the top section and finishes on the bottom.

Wrap all the sections in a single container and apply the gradient to that instead.

Wrap your sectins in a div and apply the background on that?

unfortunately due to the nature of this build, this is not possible  @0stone0 and Rory

Then in that case there's not much other choice. You would need to apply separate gradients to each section, amending the starting/ending positions depending on the heights. As I'm sure you can see, that's not going to be a reliable or effective solution.

Found a solution, will update with a answer in a few days, thanks both. you both helped with coming up with a answer

If you know the height of each section and their number here is one line of code to solve your issue


section {
  height: 200px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

section:first-of-type {
  border-image: fill 0//0 0 calc(2*200px) /* only two sections, we don't count the first one */
    linear-gradient(rgb(0 92 109), rgb(1 12 14) 39%, rgb(1 9 10) 65%, rgb(0 93 110))
}
<section class="grad-back">one</section>
<section class="grad-back">two</section>
<section class="grad-back">three</section>



Read my article to understand how border-image works: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2024/01/css-border-image-property/

plus1 great idear, unfortunately its dynamic sizing

You can achieve this by creating an element with absolute position and then place it "under" your sections:


.grad-back {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  color: white;
}
section {
  height: 200px;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.foo {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(
    180deg,
    rgba(0, 92, 109, 1) 0%,
    rgba(1, 12, 14, 1) 39%,
    rgba(1, 9, 10, 1) 65%,
    rgba(0, 93, 110, 1) 100%
  );
}
<body>
  <section class="grad-back">one</section>
  <section class="grad-back">two</section>
  <section class="grad-back">three</section>
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>



